# How to open the title of a marker in google maps v.3 when camera arrives above it?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a few markers added on a map. I'm using a model class to hold data, so I'm adding the markers using the following code:

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(model.getLat(), model.getLng());
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(model.getName());
googleMap.addMarker(marker);
```

I'm also using a method to move the camera to a specific position on user click. My method looks like this:

```
private void moveCamera(Model model) {
    moveCamera(new LatLng(model.getLat(), model.getLng()), DEFAULT_ZOOM);
}
```

So when the user clicks on the name of a location which is in a list, I'm moving the camera over that location. How can I automatically open the title of that marker, when the camera arrives above that location?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this code to create your `MarkerOptions`:

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(model.getLat(), model.getLng());
MarkerOptions markerOption = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(model.getName());
```

When you add the `Marker` to your map just keep a reference to the object:

```
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOption);
```

Now you can show the info window:

```
marker.showInfoWindow();
```